# how can i focus only one button at a time and not several at the same time?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, styled-components

can you help me with styling? I have these buttons, but only one can turn blue (focus) at a time and not several at the same time

my components is like this...

```
import { Container, Content } from './styles';

function PressedButton({ children, ...rest }) {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content
        type="button" {...rest}
        pressed={pressed}
        onFocus={() => setPressed(!pressed)}
        >
      {children}
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

styles of PressedButton...

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
(...)
export const Content = styled.button`
  (...)

  //props
  background: ${({ pressed })  => pressed ? `linear-gradient(#449fd8, #1b699a)`: '#2a2a2a'};
  color: ${({ pressed })  => pressed ? '#fff': '#7d7d7d'};
```

[my problem rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLePK.gif)

in the parent is rendering like this...

```
tags.forEach((tag) => {
    let saida = <PressedButton onClick={() => handleTag(tag)}>{tag}</PressedButton>
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show the code for the parent component? Most likely, you will need to lift state up to your parent component (the component that renders the `PressedButton` component in order to make sure only one is focused at a time.

Comment: I edited my question!

Comment: One moment, I'm making a post that should be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could look something like this to achieve what you're looking for:

```js
function parentComponet() {
  // vvv this was added vvv
  const [pressedIndex, setPressedIndex] = useState(null);
  // ... everything else
  // vvv code was added here too compare to your original code vvv
  tags.forEach((tag, index) => {
    let saida = <PressedButton pressed={pressedIndex === index} onClick={() => {handleTag(tag); setPressedIndex(index)}}>{tag}</PressedButton>
}
```

And then on the child:

```js
function PressedButton({ children, pressed, ...rest }) {
  // vvv this was removed vvv
  // const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Content
        type="button" {...rest}
        pressed={pressed}
        onFocus={() => setPressed(!pressed)}
        >
      {children}
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Essentially what this is doing is moving the state up to the parent component. This is inline with react state methodology that if you have a piece of state that needs to be coordinated between buttons, then you should move that state up to the component that is responsible for rendering the buttons.

Comment: in my example, and if I want to disable PressedIndex when the user clicks the button again, how would it look?

Comment: To achieve something like this, you would want to probably change `onClick={() => {handleTag(tag); setPressedIndex(index)}}` a little bit. What you would need to do is check if the index is equal to the current pressed index and if so, set the pressed index to null instead of the index. I'll leave the actual code to you as the best way to reinforce a simple concept is to implement it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

I can propose something like this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-thunder-c8y6g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FDemo.jsx&theme=dark)

My idea is to store in the state id or other identification of the buttons and push or remove id on click

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Nick, but in the example you sent me, the buttons are also being pressed at the same time. I need only one to be pressed at a time

Comment: Like a radio button? For example, if one button is active and I pressing another one - the prev button must become unchecked, right?

Comment: Yes I think they're looking for a radio button type solution

Comment: @eduardomarr here is the [updated variant](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-buttons-v2-yry2j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FDemo.jsx&theme=dark). Also added 2 variants of functionality (check code comments)